# Python: Starting/getting item of generator at some iteration point

Tags: python, generator

So let's imagine we have a generator, but I'd like to start calculating items from 1500 iteration, instead of start (0). Is there any better way to do that, than just making a lot of `next(generator)` callings?

Comment: yes, look at `itertools.islice`

Comment: Use `itertools.islice` but it *will* just call `next` under the hood, there is no way to avoid that

Comment: Yeah! Thank you all for the help. That was fast!